# Why python arguments change sometimes?

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is the code I type. Here the value of int has not changed outside of function but value of list has changed.I was expecting the value of list will not change. What is the reason?

```
>>> def p1(list1):
    list1[0]=1000

>>> def p2(i):
    i+=10

>>> li=[1,2,3,4,5]
>>> int1=10
>>> p1(li)
>>> p2(int1)
>>> li
[1000, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> int1
10
```

Comment: Lists are mutable, ints are immutable.

Comment: @MattDMo: No, this isn't a default argument issue. This code has no default arguments.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I pass a variable by reference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference)

Comment: You can't change an `int` in Python, you can only create a new `int` object, regardless of the operation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that in `p1`, you are *not* assigning a value to `list1`, which is the name of a variable local to `p1`. You are actually assigning to the first element of the `list` object *referenced* by `list1`, which is the same `list` object referenced by `li` in the enclosing scope.

In `p2`, on the other hand, `i+=10` *does* assign a value to the local variable `i`, not the variable `int1` in the enclosing scope. This is because the `+=` operator on objects of type `int` do not actually modify the object, but return a new object instead. (That is, for an `int`, `i+=10` is equivalent to `i = i + 10`.)

---

Just to show that `+=` *can* operate on the underlying object directly, consider this function:

```
def p3(list1):
    list1 += [10]
```

Then run it on a list:

```
>>> foo = [1,2,3]
>>> p3(list1)
>>> foo
[1, 2, 3, 10]
```

Here, the call `list1 += [10]` is really equivalent to `list1.extend([10])`, not `list1 = list1 + [10]`, due to how `list.__iadd__` is defined. Here, you are again not assigning a value to the name `list1`, but rather invoking a method on the object referenced by `list1` (which is the same object referenced by `foo`).

(Update: as pointed out by user2357112, technically you *do* assign to `list1`, but `list.__iadd__` is designed to properly assign the same list back, so that the end result is that you still have a reference to the same mutable object you started with.)

Comment: Pedantically speaking, `list1 += [10]` does `list1.extend([10])` (or an equivalent internal call), but it *also* assigns a value to `list1`. It's just that it assigns the same list to `list1` that the variable already referred to. It would be possible, though generally a bad idea, to write a class where `+=` both mutates the object and assigns a new object to the variable.

Comment: Ah, you're right. The behavior of `+=` (the operator) is consistent for `int` and `list`, but `list.__iadd__` is defined sanely :)

Comment: You've put your update in the wrong place. `p1` doesn't reassign `list1` anywhere; I was talking about your `p3` function.

Answer (score 3):

Assigning to a variable, like `i+=10`, is an operation on a variable, while index assignment, like `list1[0]=1000`, is an operation on the object a variable refers to.

When you call `p2(int1)`, the local variable `i` gets set to refer to the int `int1` referred to, and then the `i+=10` statement redirects `i` to refer to a new, larger integer. `int1` still refers to the old integer.

When you call `p1(li)`, the local variable `list1` gets set to refer to the list `li` referred to, and then the `list1[0]=1000` statement sets the first cell of the list to refer to `1000`. `li` still points to this list throughout the modification, and after the function returns, `li` still reflects the change.

(There's another complexity here in that `+=` also requests that an object mutate itself if it's mutable, in addition to performing an assignment, but that doesn't come up in this code.)

Answer (score -1):

A list is like a pointer to a list object.

```
#For example
a =[0,0]
b = a
b[0]=1
```

resulting in

```
b 
[1,0]
```

Where as an int is an a different beast

```
#For Example
a = 0
b = a
b +=1
```

resulting in

```
a 
1
```

to get the int behaviour from a listyou can make a clone of a list by passing it to list()

```
#for example
a = [0,0]
b = list(a)
b[0]=1
```

resulting in

```
a
[0,0]
```

and if you want the list behaviour from an int I guess you would have to just put it in a list.

Comment: `array` and `list` are not interchangeable terms in Python.

Comment: Np.arrays have the same behaviour in this matter.